# Unable to load OrientDB rw - "Cannot load database's configuration. The database seems to be corrupted."

Tags: java, database, orientdb

I am trying to configure a database for an application I am writing. I have started up the OrientDB server and have created a database, as well as a username and password. I hope to be able to tie my application to this, but I am currently in testing phases.

Here is the test:`    static OObjectDatabaseTx db;
    static people.Group group;

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    try {

        db = new OObjectDatabaseTx("local:/Users/<me>/Documents/Java/OrientDB/Sources/releases/orientdb-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT/databases/people");
        System.out.println("db made");
        db.open("nick", "nick");
        System.out.println("db open");



        group = new people.Group();
        System.out.println("group made");

        db.save(group);

        System.out.println("group saved");
        System.out.println(group);


    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Not succeed - " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        if( db != null ) {
            db.close();
        }

    }

}`
```

and when run, the output:

db made
Not succeed - Cannot open local storage '/Users//Documents/Java/OrientDB/Sources/releases/orientdb-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT/databases/people' with mode=rw
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage '/Users//Documents/Java/OrientDB/Sources/releases/orientdb-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT/databases/people' with mode=rw
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OStorageLocal.open(OStorageLocal.java:204)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.open(ODatabaseRaw.java:93)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:47)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.open(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:111)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:47)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:47)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.object.db.OObjectDatabaseTx.open(OObjectDatabaseTx.java:99)
    at db.ToFromByte.main(ToFromByte.java:34)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Cannot load database's configuration. The database seems to be corrupted.
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OStorageConfigurationSegment.load(OStorageConfigurationSegment.java:73)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OStorageLocal.addDefaultClusters(OStorageLocal.java:215)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OStorageLocal.open(OStorageLocal.java:143)
    ... 7 more

So the code fails on this line of code:             db.open("nick", "nick");
What could be happening here? The database seems to be accessible through the OrientDB server.

Comment: You must shutdown the server if you access it locally.

Comment: after shutting down the server, I see the exact same result.

Comment: how did you managed at the end nmio ?

Comment: Sorry Lau Llobet, its been too long and I cant recall. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the database is corrupted right now because both server and local run concurrently?